# Can Spring XD processor split payload and send them to a sink module?

Tags: java, spring, spring-xd

I was wondering if the Spring XD processor can iterate through a list and send each object in the list to a sink instead of just piping out the list as an object to a sink. This is because my sink interface provided is only taking in and processing a single object to a file.

Thanks,
RemicoAL

Answer (score 0):

Yes; see the (appropriately named) [splitter module](http://docs.spring.io/spring-xd/docs/1.3.0.RELEASE/reference/html/#splitter). If the payload is already a list, it needs no configuration.

```
... | processorThatCreatesAList | splitter | sink
```